# Why are my style elements not working?

Tags: html

I am new to html, so kindly forgive any syntax errors. However, I am trying to center text to no avail.

My code looks like this:

```
<h1> style="text-align:center">center text</h1>
```

In the browser, it returned this:

`<tag style="text-align:center">`center it

I copied and pasted a code similar in every way-as far as I can tell and it did display correctly. Here is the code I copied:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center">Centered Heading</h1>
```

Could someone kindly point out why mine returned the style attribute text?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed this:

```
 <h1> style="text-align:center">center text</h2>
<!--^ Don't close. ---------------------------^ Wrong tag.
```

And your closing tag is not the same as the starting tag.

**Correct code:**

```
<h1 style="text-align:center">center text</h1>
```

See the working of the same code in the snippet below:

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">center text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty obvious...
The starting tag was closed with '>'. 
Problem was solved by opening the starting tag. Hence, `<h1>`becomes `<h1` 
The code now looks like this;`<h1 style="text-align:center">center text</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter your style inside the starting `h1` tag like this:

`<h1 style="text-align:center"> center text </h1>`

Just remove the > symbol in starting h1 tag and remove the > symbol which is after the `style="text-align:center"`  you will get centered heading